# How to run a GUI program on windows as administrator on a user account?

Tags: windows

I am making a test program called ResourceManager(RMTest) that tries to access an image "resource.jpg" in the same directory.

resource.jpg has access set to deny for all non administrator accounts on my system, ensuring that the user cannot view it directly.

RMTest is a password prompt form that has hardcoded password that it checks against, and if it matches, it opens another form that has a picturebox control that opens the image.

I want to let normal users run this program as administrator, hopefully with the following restrictions:

1. the user is not allowed to access the memory of the program as it is being executed.
2. the user is not allowed to access the instructions of the program through disassembler/hex editor.

In turn, I expect the program to indirectly grant access to the resource through this program.

I know this can be easily done on Linux, but on Windows I only found two solutions which don't work:

1. using task scheduler that runs the program with administrative privileges when a batch file runs 'schtasks /run /TN "RMTest"'

It seems I can't run a form application on an account of a different user than that which created the task.

2. C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:MYPCNAME\Administrator /savecred "C:\RMTest\ResourceManager.exe"

This runs but gives the same exception as though no rights were granted.

---

Is there a way to do this in Windows, and if so, how?

Comment: If the image is important this will not protect it, all they have to do is boot off a live media and all file permissions are forgotten.

Comment: Although if you take assumption 2 to be true (no disassembler) you can encrypt the file and have the program only decrypt it if it is running as administrator.

Comment: @AstroDan I am aware of that but for the sake of the test I am assuming the user has no means to boot off a live media. I am only interested in demonstrating ability to do this to myself.